# How to download bulk files from azure blob storage using asp.net core WebAPI in Streaming Concept (like torrent file downloading)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I am downloading files in local storage. But Actually what I need is,
I am passing blob URIs to web API through the console application then the streaming chunk file should download in the console application Not in the local path.The chucnk file response should send to console application.

Thanks advance.

```
   [HttpPost("BulkDownload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BulkDownload(List<string> fileUris)
    {
        try
        {
            var localPath = _configuration.GetSection("LocalPath")["BulkDownload"]; // Specify the local path to download the files
            var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureBlobStorage");
            if (!Directory.Exists(localPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
            }

            foreach (var fileUri in fileUris)
            {
                var blobUri = new Uri(fileUri);
                var blobpath = Path.GetFileName(blobUri.LocalPath);
                var blobName = ("StreamProduct/cr/en/") + Path.GetFileName(blobUri.LocalPath);
                var containerName = blobUri.Segments[1].TrimEnd('/');

                var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

                var retryCount = 3;
                var success = false;
                var attempt = 1;

                var localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, blobpath);

                while (!success && attempt <= retryCount)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

                        var blobDownloadResponse = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();

                        using (var localFileStream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            var buffer = new byte[8192];
                            var bytesRead = 0;
                            
                            while ((bytesRead = await blobDownloadResponse.Value.Content.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                await localFileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                        success = true; // File downloaded successfully
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // Log or handle the exception
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading file: {ex.Message}");
                        attempt++; // Retry
                    }
                }

                if (!success)
                {
                    // Handle the scenario when download fails after retries
                    Console.WriteLine("File download failed after multiple retries.");
                }
            }

            return Ok("Files downloaded successfully to the local path.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log or handle any unexpected errors
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while performing the bulk download.");
        }
    }
```